# Define Route with Gateway and NetIf

Tags: macos, network, vpn

Hi I'm using some VPN software that isn't the default OSx VPN support.

When it connects it clobbers my routing table, putting all traffic through the VPN.

What I want to do is have something like this route defined (I see this auto defined when I'm not on the VPN) ...

```
Destination  Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
192.168.1.2  a0:21:b7:c1:91:64  UHLWI           0        3     en3
```

Where that Gateway Address is the Mac address of the 192.168.1.2 machine.

When I connect the VPN and new Netif is added "utune0"

So I've tried

```
sudo route add -host 192.168.1.2 -link a0:21:b7:c1:91:64
```

... And end up with

```
Destination  Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
192.168.1.2  a0:21.b7.c1.91.64  UGHS            0        0   utun0
```

... So wrong netif

The I try and add the -interface option

```
sudo route add -host 192.168.1.2 -interface en3  -link a0:21:b7:c1:91:64
```

... I End up with

```
Destination  Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
192.168.1.2  10:dd:b1:a0:af:43  UHLS            0        0   en3
```

... where that gateway address is wrong, it is the mac address of my machines en3 adaptor....

Any ideas how to get the initial route I wanted?

Comment: Have you checked your VPN client for routing options? Most offer at least some option on what traffic to route through the VPN connection.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Nah there are no options for setting that. looked at that before looking at anything else.